# Angular ngx-bootstrap Typeahead : optionsListTemplate with table view

Tags: angular, typeahead, ngx-bootstrap

I want to show results of the type ahead search in tabular format and not_as list drop down. I followed following - [valor github](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/1557)

I'll will be searching against 3 coulmn values in table and that part is taken care using filters. I'm not sure about displaying search results in tables and how events like 'click on a row' in table etc can be handled using typeahead plugin.Also I see I would need to do lot of styling for displaying data in proper tabular format, will typeahead plugin's css work smoothly with custom css which I'll be having for tables?

I have below template -

```
<ng-template #customItemTemplate>
<div class="col-lg-12 sb-ir-popover-table-div sb-ir-popover-table-layout">
      <table class="table-hover table-striped">
        <thead>
            <th class="sb-ir-popover-table-th">name</th>
            <th class="sb-ir-popover-table-th">region</th>
        </thead>
          <tr>
        <td>{{state.name}}</td> // I get error here - ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined(…)
        <td>{{state.region}}</td>
     </tr>
      </table>
</div>
</ng-template>
```

How do I get hold of 'state.name' / 'region' or search result 'state' objects in custom template?

my input is like this -

```
<input [(ngModel)]="asyncSelected"
     [typeahead]="dataSource"
     (typeaheadLoading)="changeTypeaheadLoading($event)"
     (typeaheadNoResults)="TypeaheadNoResults($event)"
     (typeaheadOnSelect)="typeaheadOnSelect($event)"
     typeaheadOptionsLimit="15"
     [optionsListTemplate]="customItemTemplate"
     placeholder="Locations loaded with timeout"
     class="form-control">
```

In above mentioned link, I see following method calls -

```
[class.active]="isActive(match)"
(mouseenter)="selectActive(match)"
(click)="selectMatch(match, $event)"
```

wanted to check if I would need to override all method calls (including above ones) with custom implementation to support events for tabular display of data.

Earlier I was using following -

Input -

```
typeaheadOptionField="combined"
```

It's this 'combined' which was getting displayed as options and now I want to change that options to tabular form with original columns.

**Component:**

```
public statesComplex: any[] = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Alabama', region: 'South'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Alaska',    region: 'West'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Arizona', region: 'West'},
  {id: 4, name: 'Arkansas', region: 'South'}];

public constructor() {
  this.dataSource = Observable
  .create((observer: any) => {
    // Runs on every search
    observer.next(this.asyncSelected);
  })
  .mergeMap((token: string) => this.getStatesAsObservable(token));
}

public getStatesAsObservable(token: string): Observable<any> {
  return Observable.of(
  this.statesComplex.filter((state: any) => {
    state['combined'] = state.name+'--->'+state.region;
    return state.combined.toLowerCase().indexOf(token.toLowerCase())>-1;
  })
 );
}
```

This worked fine, but i wanted tabular display of 'state' object fields without ' --->' .

**UPDATE-1**

I missed for loop in custom template and after adding that I'm able to get all state values in tabular format. But its not filtering as and when i type. What attribute/methods should I use so that i can get filtered results. As posted earlier I've a filter in constructor which was working fine as long as results was in dropdown view.

I've following now in custom template -

```
<tr *ngFor='let state of statesComplex'>//missed this for loop earlier
        <td>{{state.name}}</td>
        <td>{{state.region}}</td>
</tr>
```

I see following attribute being used in reference link -

```
typeahead="item as item.title + ' (' + item.name + ')' for item in data | filter:{title:$viewValue}"
```

will this help for filtering? Can you please explain what's $viewValue and how i can use my already existing filter logic here. Also I've doubts if I need to mandatorily use below lines in custom template so that it displays filtered results there.

```
<template ngFor let-match let-i="index" [ngForOf]="matches">
<template [ngTemplateOutlet]="itemTemplate || bsItemTemplate"
                                                      [ngOutletContext]="
{item:match.item, index:i, match:match, query:query}" style="color: black;">
```

Comment: Any one has a solution to display the ngx-bootstrap typeahead in a tabular way ?